# Assign different passwords to different files

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have the below table in Excel with different file names and its path.
How can I assign a password to all those Excel workbooks?

Let's say for file path in Cell B2 should be assigned with password in C2
file path in Cell B3 should be assigned with password in C3... etc.

Excel file
[image]

I found VBA codes to assign one single password to all the files under the same folder, but over 1000 files need to be assigned different passwords. I also need to remove all the passwords later.

Comment: Your VBA should loop through the rows, open each file, save it with the corresponding password, and finally close the file. There is nothing too complex in here.

Comment: @FDavidov thanks! i can find a code to assign one single password to all the files into the folder. but i dont know how to change it to fit my scanario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare two variables one to hold a Filename while the other the password.

Then, you only need one single loop (and not two) in which you would need to:

1. Build the full name of the file you want to set the password (in fact, you have it in column B of your example),
2. Get the password that needs to be used for this file (column C in your example),
3. Open the file whose name you extracted,
4. SaveAs with the password you extracted,
5. Close the file.

The loop should exit as soon as the retrieved filename is empty.

This description might need complex, but I assure you it is very simple. Just give it a couple of tries and you will experience the satisfaction of building something by yourself.

Hint: Excel's VB editor enables you to set breakpoints to halt execution and examine the value of variables; this will also help you to better understand what you are doing and, if something is not working, quickly find out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much!! You are right! I should learn how to craft the code myself! I will look at your tips and instruction tomorrow! (It's now midnight in my city!)

Comment: Wish you a pleasant rest and that you wake up with renewed energy. I'm sure you will manage it since all you need is already in the code you posted. By the way, if you consider that my posted answer helped you, you may wish to up-vote it and mark it as an answer (click the "V" at the left of the answer). Good night!!!

Answer (score 0):

@FDavidov

thanks! i can find a code to assign one single password to all the files into the folder. but i dont know how to change it to fit my scanario. anyone can advise how i should change? thanks!!!

Public Sub addPassword()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim folder As Object, subfolder As Object
    Dim wb As Object

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folderPath = ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value
pwd = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value
Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

For Each wb In folder.Files
    If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
        Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End If
Next
For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    For Each wb In subfolder.Files
        If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End If
    Next
Next
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Should I understand that you are not only new in VBA but also in programming as a whole? The reason for having all fines with the same password is quite clear: You are fetching the password only once (3rd line of the posted code) instead of doing it for each file. Note also that the code goes to sub-folders (which, according to your example, is not your case).

Comment: @FDavidov yes sorry i m a non-English native speaker, so i didn't describe myself correctly...i'm not new to VBA .  actually, I got no clue on VBA, just started today. I just spent whole night searching on Google because of my working need. i know the code i found can't fit in this scenario but i really dont know how to change it to better fit my scenario,

Comment: I could make the code for you, but then you will not learn anything. Instead, I'll give you the guidelines in an answer I'll post in few minutes. Hope you accept my approach (since, at least this is my believe), you will not only gain to get what you want, but also learn how these type of things are done.